# Redux error when submitting a form: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm trying to submit a form using Redux, however, getting an error message in the console: Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions.

I am already using thunk as my middleware when creating the store. Here's the code:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

create post action:

```
export const createPosts = (post) => async (dispatch)=>{
  try {
    const {data} = await api.createPost(post)

    dispatch({type:'CREATE', payload:data})
  } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);

  }
}
```

PS: submit form works after page is refreshed

Adding the requested code as per in the comments:

createPost controller:

```
export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags } = req.body;

  const newPostMessage = new PostMessage({
    title,
    message,
    selectedFile,
    creator,
    tags,
  });

  try {
    await newPostMessage.save();

    res.status(201).json(newPostMessage);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

reducer index.js

```
import posts from "./posts";

export default combineReducers({
    posts,
})
```

post reducers:

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE':
      return posts.map((post)=>post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post)
    case "FETCH_ALL":
      return action.payload;
    case "CREATE":
      return [...posts, action.payload];

    default:
      return posts;
  }
};
```

Comment: can you add the full thunk, reducers set up code ?

Comment: doing now, will be updating the question

Comment: seems like you are not returning anything from the try catch ...

Comment: Can you show where you're dispatching the thunk?  Also, you should know that you're writing a _very_ outdated style of Redux code.  Modern Redux with Redux Toolkit is much easier to set up, learn, and use: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index .

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you cannot have an async function as an action, even with thunk.

Thunk allows you to return an async response, not call an async action. So the proper way to do this would be:

```
export const createPost = post => (dispatch, getState) => {
  api.createPost(post)
    .then(data => dispatch({ type: "CREATE", payload: data}))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

Assuming that the declaration of `createPost` is an async function or it returns a call to an async function.

Comment: Applied your code and still receiving the same error. api.createPost is an async function too.

Comment: Can you post the api.createPost definition and double-ckeck that thunk is set up correctly?

Comment: sure, updating the original post now

Comment: could you try to return something from your function in the try/except block?